# gtk disable sounds on <esc>-keypress

Tags: gtk, nixos

Since a few days, everytime I do something "invalid" in a gtk application, like pressing `esc`, when there is nothing to "escape from", or pressing backspace in an empty input field, I get a weird noise (it sounds a bit like a waterdrop).

I already tried setting this in my `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
gtk-enable-event-sounds=0
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=0
```

but that didn't change the behaviour.

In case it's relevant, I'm on NixOS unstable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found out I had to set

```
gtk-error-bell=0
```

in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`,`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and `~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini`